# Symfony2 generate form for entity of another entity (location of a shop)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity

i'm trying to figure this out for a while now.

I can't find any documentation on how to do the following:

I have 2 entities Shop and Location, a shop can have more locations
The entities are already working correctly in the database.

But now i want to make a form to add a location to a shop.
If i render the form with ->add('shop', 'entity') in the LocationType then i will get a dropdown.

What i want is a hidden (not changable) field with the shop id.

Any suggestions?

Here is my code for the LocationType: ([STORENAME] is the replacement of the name of the company)

```
class LocationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('street')
            ->add('number')
            ->add('numberAddition')
            ->add('postalcode')
            ->add('city')
            ->add('phone')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('shop', 'entity', array(
                'class' => '[STORENAME]ShopBundle:Shop',
                'property' => 'name'))
        ;
    }
```

Txs!,
Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this what you want?
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

It allows you to add one or multiple locations to a shop, from the shop form.

Comment: Txs! i think this is what i was looking for!